# Change language being spell-checked in Textmate

Tags: macos, textmate, textmate2

In OS X applications such as Mail and Firefox you can right click in a text field and change the language being spell-checked. I can't figure out how to do the same in Textmate. Can it be done easily, and if, how?

Answer (score 19):

Press <kbd>⌘:</kbd> (it's a shortcut to Edit, Spelling, Show Spelling and Grammar) and change the language in the dropdown.

To update the error highlights on the active file, press <kbd>⌥⌘;</kbd> twice to turn Check Spelling as You Type off and on again.

Answer (score 5):

Edit / Spelling /check spelling as you type (click on it to uncheck).

Comment: It sounds like they WANT the spell-check feature, they just want to change the language.  Do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no option in the TextMate preferences, there is no easy option. The only way to accomplish this is to change your preferred system language, i.e. going to "System Preferences" > "Language & Text" > "Language" and dragging the language you want to spell-check to the top. You have to log out and log in again to make this change work.

Hopefully there will be an easier solution in TextMate2.

Comment: The solution mentioned above by @dipnlik works in textmate2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Very old thread but in TextMate 2:

`Edit` -> `Spelling` -> various options to spell check are shown at the top of that menu. Below, choose `System (Automatic by Language)` ideally and it'll follow System Preferences, else choose from one of the other languages listed.

If using the "automatic" setting, you should *not* need to log in/out or restart Textmate 2 (at least, in OS X Sierra) to detect a change made in System Preferences, though you might need to toggle on and off the "system automatic" TextMate language selection if it doesn't seem to "see" the change straight away.

The <kbd>⌘:</kbd> shortcut mentioned by @dipnlik works in TextMate 2, showing a popup menu hovering under the first "underlined in red" word and is useful for its "learn spelling" and "ignore spelling" options.